# Matrix $X$ (rotation of $90$ degrees)

Tags: matrices, geometry

If the matrix $X$ represents a rotation of $90$ degrees about $(0,0)$. Determine the matrix $X$.

Since the question didn't state  if it's clockwise or anti-clockwise, is it possible to find the matrix?

Comment: Hint. The question is badly phrased. Either it should say "Determine _a_ matrix ..." or you are supposed to understand that rotations are anticlockwise by convention, so the other one would be 270 degrees or -90 degrees.

Comment: Typically the convention assumes anti-clockwise; for clockwise you would either say $270$ degrees or $-90$ degrees. However, you should just get clarification from your source.

Comment: If the answer below was helpful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be badly phrased. If there is no direction given (clockwise of anti-clockwise) then there's more than one.